# MySQL order by problems

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have the following codes..

```php
echo "<form><center><input type=submit name=subs value='Submit'></center></form>";

$val=$_POST['resulta']; //this is from a textarea name='resulta'
if (isset($_POST['subs'])) //from submit name='subs'
{
    $aa=mysql_query("select max(reservno) as 'maxr' from reservation") or die(mysql_error()); //select maximum reservno
    $bb=mysql_fetch_array($aa);
    $cc=$bb['maxr'];
    $lines = explode("\n", $val);
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        mysql_query("insert into location_list (reservno, location) values ('$cc', '$line')")
          or die(mysql_error()); //insert value of textarea then save it separately in location_list if \n is found
    }
```

If I input the following data on the textarea (assume that I have maximum reservno '00014' from reservation table),

```
Davao - Cebu
Cebu - Davao
```

then submit it, I'll have these data in my location_list table:

```
loc_id || reservno || location
00001  || 00014    || Davao - Cebu
00002  || 00014    || Cebu - Davao
```

Then this code:

```php
$gg=mysql_query("SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(IF((@var_ctr := @var_ctr + 1) = @cnt, 
                            location, 
                            SUBSTRING_INDEX(location,' - ', 1)
                           ) 
                           ORDER BY loc_id ASC
                           SEPARATOR ' - ') AS locations

    FROM location_list, 
         (SELECT @cnt := COUNT(1), @var_ctr := 0 
          FROM location_list 
          WHERE reservno='$cc'
         ) dummy
    WHERE reservno='$cc'") or die(mysql_error()); //QUERY IN QUESTION
    $hh=mysql_fetch_array($gg);
    $ii=$hh['locations'];
    mysql_query("update reservation set itinerary = '$ii' where reservno = '$cc'")
      or die(mysql_error());
```

is supposed to update reservation table with `'Davao - Cebu - Davao'` but it's returning this instead, `'Davao - Cebu - Cebu'`. I was previously helped by this forum to have this code working but now I'm facing another difficulty. Just can't get it to work. Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Omesh, I'm crediting this code to you. :)) Please continue on helping me get this work. Thanks

Comment: Ya sure, you can post link to your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171581/mysql-string-functions/12171808#comment16410367_12171808

Comment: You really really need to start normalizing. you're tearing apart a string, just to rebuild it again...

Comment: @MarcB, yeah, I'll do just that after getting this problem work. One problem at a time. I'm not that genius. :))) Thanks for the advise though. :)))

Comment: What is datatype of `loc_id`? It should be `INT`. Can you post your Mysql version?

Comment: @Omesh, yes it's datatype is INT(5), unsigned zerofill, auto-increment and it is the primary key. MySQL client version 5.1.41

Comment: please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: @alfasin, noted. I'll get on it after this issue. Thanks. :)

Comment: can you setup exact sqlfiddle for your data? and it could be a problem with your client. If possible try changing it.

Comment: @Omesh, it is working properly here, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7a12/1 but using the code above, it doesn't.

Comment: @Omesh, when I remove the order by clause on the query, this is what I get, 'Cebu - Davao - Cebu', which should be 'Davao - Cebu - Davao'. I think this happens because of the insertion. 'Davao - Cebu' is placed under 'Cebu - Davao', which is on top. So the query reads the 'Cebu - Davao' first. (Noticed this after looking back and forth to my code, running browser then to phpMyAdmin) Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: I hope you got your answer. You need to store records in ascending order of `loc_id`. There is no other way to know the order of your records.

Comment: @Omesh, I notice something again. The query above works when I run it in phpmyadmin sql query window. How can I get it work through PHP? I can't really rely on the ascending operation on phpmyadmin 'cause it changes whenever the data on the table are deleted or the data are returned on the 2nd page. Please help me. I don't know what to do anymore. :(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working (without `ORDER BY loc_id ASC`) as long as I set phpMyAdmin operations loc_id ascending. But whenever I delete all data, it goes back as loc_id descending so I have to reset it. It doesn't entirely solve the problem but I guess this is as far as I can go. :)) I just have to make sure that the table column loc_id is always in ascending order. Thank you everyone for your help! I really appreciate it! But if you have any better answer, like how to set the table column always in ascending order or better query, etc, feel free to post it here. May God bless you all!

Answer (score 0):

The database server is allowed to rewrite your query to optimize its execution. This might affect the order of the individual parts, in particular the order in which the various assignments are executed. I assume that some such reodering causes the result of the query to become undefined, in such a way that it works on sqlfiddle but not on your actual production system.

I can't put my finger on the exact location where things go wrong, but I believe that the core of the problem is the fact that SQL is intended to work on relations, but you try to abuse it for sequential programming. **I suggest you retrieve the data from the database using portable SQL without any variable hackery, and then use PHP to perform any post-processing you might need.** PHP is much better suited to express the ideas you're formulating, and no optimization or reordering of statements will get in your way there. And as your query currently only results in a single value, fetching multiple rows and combining them into a single value in the PHP code shouldn't increase complexety too much.

---

## Edit:

While [discussing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275048/get-a-query-to-list-the-records-that-are-on-and-in-between-the-start-and-the-end#comment16465116_12275747) [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12275747/1468366) using a similar technique (by [Omesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1514653/omesh) as well, just as [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12171808/1468366) your code is based upon), I found this in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html):

> As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable
> and read the value within the same statement. You might get the
> results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. The order of
> evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined and
> may change based on the elements contained within a given statement;
> in addition, this order is not guaranteed to be the same between
> releases of the MySQL Server.

So there are no guarantees about the order these variable assignments are evaluated, therefore no guarantees that the query does what you expect. It might work, but it might fail suddenly and unexpectedly. Therefore I strongly suggest you avoid this approach unless you have some relaibale mechanism to check the validity of the results, or really don't care about whether they are valid.