# Get a query to list the records that are on and in between the start and the end values of a particular column for the same Id

Tags: mysql

There is a table with the columns :

```
USE 'table';  
insert into person values   
('11','xxx','1976-05-10','p1'),  
('11','xxx ','1976-06-11','p1'),  
('11','xxx ','1976-07-21','p2'),  
('11','xxx ','1976-08-31','p2'),
```

Can anyone suggest me a query to get the start and the end date of the person with respect to the place he changed chronologically.

The query I wrote

```
SELECT PId,Name,min(Start_Date) as sdt, max(Start_Date) as edt, place 
from ** 
group by Place;
```

only gives me the first two rows of my answer. Can anyone suggest the query??

Comment: Your question is very much based on the order of rows, and whether or not two subsequent rows identify the same place. These things are hard to express in SQL, and often better tackled at the application level. [Fiddle available](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1a86) for those who want to give it a try nevertheless.

Comment: If you wish to anonymize your code, please do so without destroying the question and answers. I've rolled this back to an earlier intact version.

Comment: As a warning, do not wipe all of your code again. You can anonymize the data and names here, but you need to preserve the core question. Your edits so far have made the question meaningless, so I've had to roll them back twice.

Comment: This is the right question for the answer though modified. Sorry to trouble you. @ Brad Larson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't pretty, and performance might be horrible, but at least it [works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1a86/24):

```
select min(sdt), edt, place
from (
  select A.Start_Date sdt, max(B.Start_Date) edt, A.place
  from person A
       inner join person B on A.place = B.place
                          and A.Start_Date <= B.Start_Date
       left join person C on A.place != C.place
                         and A.Start_Date < C.Start_Date
                         and C.Start_Date < B.Start_Date
  where C.place is null
  group by A.Start_Date, A.place
) X
group by edt, place
```

The idea is that `A` and `B` represent all *pairs* of rows. `C` will be any row in between these two which has a different `place`. So after the `C.place is null` restriction, we know that `A` and `B` belong to the same range, i.e. a group of rows for one place with no other place in between them in chronological order. From all these pairs, we want to identify those with maximal range, those which encompass all others. We do so using two nested `group by` queries. The inner one will choose the maximal end date for every possible start date, whereas the outer one will choose the minimal start date for every possible end date. The result are maximal ranges of chronologically subsequent rows describing the same place.

Comment: OMG..!! I cant believe this.It worked. I never thought, I could ever get the answer. But a very tactful solution.Thank you.

Comment: The above query worked perfect for only 1 id "10---01".Not working when such ID's are added. Can there be a change in the query??

Comment: @user1635134: Your original query (which is now missing from the question!) didn't care about ids either, so I kept mine just as simple. To do everything per id, you have to include the id a) in the join conditions of both joins, b) in both group by conditions and c) as an additional column in the result of the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achived by:

```
SELECT Id, PId,
       MIN(Start_Date) AS sdt,
       MAX(Start_Date) as edt,
       IF(`place` <> @var_place_prev, (@var_rank:= @var_rank + 1), @var_rank) AS rank,
       (@var_place_prev := `place`) AS `place`
FROM person, (SELECT @var_rank := 0, @var_place_prev := "") dummy
GROUP BY rank, Place;
```

## Example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1a86/23)

If you want records to be ordered by `ID` then:

```
SELECT Id, PId,
       MIN(Start_Date) AS sdt,
       MAX(Start_Date) as edt,
       `place`
FROM(
     SELECT Id, PId,
            Start_Date
            IF(`place` <> @var_place_prev,(@var_rank:= @var_rank + 1),@var_rank) AS rank,
            (@var_place_prev := `place`) AS `place`
     FROM person, (SELECT @var_rank := 0, @var_place_prev := "") dummy
     ORDER BY ID ASC
    ) a
GROUP BY rank, Place;
```

Comment: Your solution very much relies on the order in which MySQL traverses the table. If that order [changes](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aea44/1), your result becomes incorrect. As MySQL doesn't make any guarantees about the order in which it processes its relations, your query is likely to produce incorrect results, either now or at some point in the future, after some change to the data or a database server upgrade.

Comment: Ya right! Second query guarantees order of records. I purposely posted  first query as it performs much better than second.

Comment: Sorry to spoil the fun, but second query [suffers](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aea44/3) from the same problem. The reason is that the column values will get computed before the `ORDER BY` applies. So the `ORDER BY` has no impact on the order in which the variable assignments are processed. Apparently you can [fix](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aea44/4) this by replacing the table reference with a subquery which orders, but I haven't found any guarantees in the MySQL manual that this will always work.

Comment: Note that according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12243779/1468366), a query using a similar technique (based on [one of your answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12171808/1468366)) suddenly stopped working if executed in a different environment. Makes me think that unless I exactly know from the manual under what circumstances I can rely on the order of execution, I'd rather not rely on it at all.

Comment: OK, according to [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html): “As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. You might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined and may change based on the elements contained within a given statement; in addition, this order is not guaranteed to be the same between releases of the MySQL Server.“ So there are no guarantees whatsoever.