# subtract the data for every 5 minutes between two particular times

Tags: mysql

I have some problem with MYSQL,I need to subtract the data between two particular times,for every 5 minutes and then average it the 5 minutes data.
What I am doing now is:

```
select (avg(columnname)),convert((min(datetime) div 500)*500, datetime) + INTERVAL 5 minute as endOfInterval 
from Databasename.Tablename 
where datetime BETWEEN '2012-09-12 10:50:00' AND '2012-09-12 14:50:00' 
group by datetime div 500;
```

It is the cumulative average.
Suppose i get 500 at 11 o' clock and 700 at 11.05 ,the average i need is (700-500)/5 = 40.
But now i am getting (500+700)/5 = 240.
I dont need the cumulative average .
Kindly help me.

Comment: If you include test data in this question you will have a much better chance of getting a good answer. Preferably with `create` and `include` statements.

Comment: By the way: with `avg` you won't get `(500+700)/5 = 240` but instead `(500+700)/2 = 600`, as it averages by count without paying any special attention to associated times. To divide by 5 you'd have to provide 5 rows of input, i.e. `(…+…+…+…+…)/5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the kind of average you're talking about, you don't want to *aggregate* multiple rows using a `GROUP BY` clause. INstead, you want to compute your result using exactly *two diffrent rows* from the same table. This calls for a self-join:

```
SELECT (b.columnname - a.columnname)/5, a.datetime, b.datetime
FROM Database.Tablename a, Database.Tablename b
WHERE b.datetime = a.datetime + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
  AND a.datetime BETWEEN '2012-09-12 10:50:00' AND '2012-09-12 14:45:00'
```

`a` and `b` refer to two different rows of the same table. The `WHERE` clause ensures that they are exactly 5 minutes apart.

If there is no second column matching that temporal distance, no resulting row will be included in the query result. If your table doesn't have data points exactly every five minutes, but you have to search for the suitable partner instead, then things become much more difficult. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12275621/1468366) might perhaps be adjusted for that use case. Or you might implement this at the application level, instead of on the database server.