# difference of two rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need the difference of two rows

```
SELECT ( b.l2framessent - a.l2framessent ), 
       CONVERT((Min(a.datetime) DIV 500)*500, datetime) 
       + INTERVAL 5 minute AS endOfInterval 
FROM   databasename.tablename a, 
       databasename.tablename b 
WHERE  a.ipaddress = 'moteid6' 
       AND b.ipaddress = 'moteid6' 
       AND a.datetime BETWEEN '2012-09-25 15:45:00' AND '2012-09-25 18:45:00' 
GROUP  BY a.datetime DIV 500;
```

Both the rows are from same Table,Database and same column

i am getting negative and irrelevant values

How to get the correct values

```
select datetime, l2framessent 
from 6panview.Statistics3 
where ipaddress = 'moteid6' 
    AND datetime BETWEEN '2012-09-25 15:45:00' AND '2012-09-25 18:50:00';

+---------------------+--------------+
| datetime            | l2framessent |
+---------------------+--------------+
| 2012-09-25 17:45:56 |  25 |
| 2012-09-25 17:50:35 |  56 |
| 2012-09-25 17:55:15 |  87 |
| 2012-09-25 17:59:54 | 117 |
| 2012-09-25 18:04:33 | 148 |
| 2012-09-25 18:09:13 | 178 |
| 2012-09-25 18:13:52 | 208 |
| 2012-09-25 18:18:31 | 238 |
| 2012-09-25 18:23:10 | 269 |
| 2012-09-25 18:39:43 | 372 |
| 2012-09-25 18:44:23 | 402 |
| 2012-09-25 18:49:02 | 432 |
+---------------------+-----+
```

Comment: When you use GROUP BY, all the return values should either be the columns you're grouping by or aggregate functions. `( b.l2framessent - a.l2framessent )` is not one of these.

Comment: If i dont use GROUP BY ,i am  getting only 1 value.ie., only the first value

Comment: That's because you have an aggregation function in your query, so it aggregates all the rows. You should move that into a subquery and join with it.

Comment: Thankyou,I dont have an idea of subquerying and joining

Comment: I think I know how to fix it, but I'm not really sure what your query is trying to do. Could you add some explanation to the question?

Comment: Ok,Sure.I have the data ie., L2FramesSent for every 5 minutes for a particular mote.Suppose at 10.05 we get 300 and at 10.10 we get 350.

Comment: That is,actually 50 were sent in the 5 minute period for that mote.I actually need it.So, i am subtracting second row from the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working query. And you were right in the first place to divide and multiply by 500, I didn't realize how MySQL converts datetimes to numbers.

```
SELECT ( b.l2framessent - a.l2framessent ), 
       CONVERT(endOfInterval*500, DATETIME) endOfInterval
FROM   (SELECT datetime DIV 500 startOfInterval,
               l2framessent
        FROM tablename,
             (SELECT MIN(datetime) mindate
              FROM tablename
              WHERE ipaddress = 'moteid6'
                    AND datetime BETWEEN '2012-09-25 15:45:00' AND '2012-09-25 18:45:00'
              GROUP BY datetime DIV 500) b
        WHERE ipaddress = 'moteid6'
              AND datetime = mindate
       ) a, 
       (SELECT datetime DIV 500 endOfInterval,
               l2framessent
        FROM tablename,
             (SELECT MIN(datetime) mindate
              FROM tablename
              WHERE ipaddress = 'moteid6'
                    AND datetime BETWEEN '2012-09-25 15:45:00' AND '2012-09-25 18:45:00'
              GROUP BY datetime DIV 500) b
        WHERE ipaddress = 'moteid6'
              AND datetime = mindate
       ) b
WHERE endOfInterval = startOfInterval + 1
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96eb5/10)

Comment: Thankyou,But i am getting NULL.Empty set (0.02 sec)

Comment: Put the output of `select datetime, l2framessent from tablename where ipaddress = 'moteid6'
              AND datetime BETWEEN '2012-09-25 15:45:00' AND '2012-09-25 18:50:00'` in your question.

Comment: +---------------------+--------------+
| datetime            | l2framessent |
+---------------------+--------------+
| 2012-09-25 17:45:56 |  25 |
| 2012-09-25 17:50:35 |  56 |
| 2012-09-25 17:55:15 |  87 |
| 2012-09-25 17:59:54 | 117 |
| 2012-09-25 18:04:33 | 148 |
| 2012-09-25 18:09:13 | 178 |
| 2012-09-25 18:13:52 | 208 |
| 2012-09-25 18:18:31 | 238 |
| 2012-09-25 18:23:10 | 269 |
| 2012-09-25 18:39:43 | 372 |
| 2012-09-25 18:44:23 | 402 |
| 2012-09-25 18:49:02 | 432 |
+---------------------+-----+

Comment: Sorry,I dont know how to put it in the question

Comment: See revised answer. It now handles the case where there are two entries in the same 5-minute period (that was what you were trying to do with your MIN and GROUP BY).

Comment: Sorry,I didn't get you.Where is the revised answer

Comment: But I didnt get some values in the middle,evenif they are present at those times.

Comment: There are no results for 18:25, 18:30, and 18:35 because either the start or end of those intervals is missing from the data. The data jumps from 18:23 to 18:39.

Comment: You going to accept my answer? You've asked 5 questions and haven't accepted any. Also, it looks like this question is almost identical to  your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475830/subtract-the-data-for-every-5-minutes-between-two-particular-times

Comment: Yes,accepting your answer.Question has some difference.The thing is i didnt ask that question properly.Should we click somewhere to accept the answer,Sorry for asking.i'm new to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Not sure, but luck if works:

```
AND a.datetime BETWEEN TO_SECONDS('2012-09-25 15:45:00') AND TO_SECONDS('2012-09-25 18:45:00')
```

Comment: Thankyou,But I am getting NULL.It has data between those timings.It should not show NULL know

Comment: Do one thing... Create a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and send us. Will send you the query. It is working perfectly.

Comment: fiddle means?Sorry to ask.Say me know

Comment: Its like in live you can create a database and query them too... :)